# Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}y_n$ if $y_1=\frac{x}{2},y_n=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y^2_{n-1}}{2},0\le x \le 1,n=2,3,...$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

Is it a good approach to use induction? If $0\le x \le 1$ then $0\le y_1 \le \frac{5}{8}$. Suppose that $$0\le y_n \le \frac{5}{8}$$ and prove $$0\le y_{n+1} \le \frac{5}{8}$$ If $$y_{n+1}=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y^2_n}{2}$$ what should be the induction step?

Comment: If $x=1$ it isn't true that $y_n\le 1/2$..

Comment: If it has a limit $y$, then $y=\frac{x}2+\frac{y^2}2$

Comment: @Michael  Yes, but I need to prove that it has a limit (convergent sequence)

Answer (score 1):

Since the only possible limits are $1\pm\sqrt{1-x}$, let $z_n=1-y_n$, find the recursion for $z_n$, and check the consequences of $z_n^2<1-x$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
We know that $y_n$ is convergent. Suppose that $y_n\rightarrow y$ then

$$y=x/2+y^2/2\rightarrow y=1-\sqrt{1-x}$$